# How does xmlSApply work?

Tags: xml, r

While working through [this tutorial](http://giventhedata.blogspot.com/2012/06/r-and-web-for-beginners-part-ii-xml-in.html) on XML in R, I ran across this code:

```
xml.url <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(xml.url)
xmltop <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
plantcat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

I understand the first three lines, however for the life of me, I do not understand the last line. Can someone explain it to me? Why is there a function(x)?

Answer (score 1):

`xmlSApply` These methods are simple wrappers for the `lapply` and `sapply` functions.

For each element in a list you apply a func.

xmlSApply(listXml,func)

Here the example is a bit complexe since it use another `xmlSApply` to define func.

For example here , the first element in xmltop is :

```
x = <PLANT>
  <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
  <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
  <ZONE>4</ZONE>
  <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
  <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
  <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
```

If you apply   xmlSApply(x, xmlValue):

```
COMMON                BOTANICAL                     ZONE                    LIGHT                    PRICE             AVAILABILITY 
"Bloodroot" "Sanguinaria canadensis"                      "4"           "Mostly Shady"                  "$2.44"                 "031599"
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simplified usage of xmlSApply() it can be understood as accessing the document (provide a document) and finding the details of the document using xmlName, xmlValue etc.
xmlSApply(X, FUN, ...)

Read more here:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XML/docs/xmlApply

For  a detailed usage kindly refer to this post in my blog:
http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-do-you-get-at-details-of-xml.html